# I need a way to Select perticular rows from one excel sheet and copy them in other if condition matches

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table1 in sheet A and a table2 in sheet B (B has 2 columns Date & ContentXYZ).

Conditions: If any cell in ContentXYZ column of Sheet B contains a substring say "abc" copy that complete row to table1 in sheet A.  Similarly this has to done for every row in Table 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple macro to do your task,

```
Sub copyrow()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
j = Sheets("SheetA").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Sheets("SheetB").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(Cells(i, 2), "abc") > 0 Then
        Sheets("SheetA").Cells((j + 1), "A") = Cells(i, 1)
        Sheets("SheetA").Cells((j + 1), "B") = Cells(i, 2)
        j = Sheets("SheetA").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This macro copies the rows from `SheetB` to `SheetA` if `abc` is present (case sensitive). Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Giving Run Time Error Object Required : For i = 2 To UsedRange.Rows.Count

Comment: @user8024441 This works great for me. However i have a made a small change to the answer. Try now

Comment: Hi, code is working but their is a issue which if you could help with would solve a lot of problems:   when it is copying data from SheetB to SheetA it copy/Paste complete ROW due to which data in other columns in sheetB is overwritten by this which cannot happen in mycase .   To elaborate if Sheet B (Column A and B are getting Copied) and Pasted (To sheet B Column A and B it should not erase data present in C and D .......) . I Have tried a lot not getting anywhere if you know of something plz help

Comment: @user8024441 I have updated the answer. Please try now it should work. Please mark answer as correct if you found this useful.